# How do I take a picture of the codes on the XCode text panel?

Tags: xcode

How do I take a picture of the codes on the XCode text panel?

I want to know this so I can upload a picture of the code that I need help on.

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Taking screenshots is more of a question for supersuer. By the way, just hit `cmd+shift+4` and select the area…

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of code to show the code you're struggling with - construct a *complete, minimal* example and show that using text formatted as code. It will be searchable that way. Screenshots of code are invariably a bad way to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Osx:

- Command+Shift+3: takes a screenshot of the full screen (or screens if multiple monitors), and save it as a file to the desktop
- Command+Shift+4: brings up a selection box so you can specify an area to take a screenshot of, then save it as a file to the desktop
- Command+Shift+4, then spacebar, then click a window: takes a screenshot of a window only and saves it as a file to the desktop

From [OSX Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2010/05/13/print-screen-mac/)

Edit: For more options, and information on file formats, see [this](http://guides.macrumors.com/Taking_Screenshots_in_Mac_OS_X) guide from MacRumors.